# scrollPanel not scroll in android

Tags: gwt, mgwt

I application developer  to mobile with mgwt.
I use in mgwt ScrollPanel to create scroll
but scrollPanel not scroll in smartphone.
when I run in dev mode on computer the scroll work fine.
I do not know why this happen
I use in LayoutPanel of mgwt to wrapper scrollPanel.
thank you

this is ScrollPanel code
    import com.googlecode.mgwt.ui.client.widget.ScrollPanel;

```
 scroll = new ScrollPanel();
 scroll.setStyleName(css.loginScroll(),true);
 scroll.clear();
 scroll.setWidget(registerForm);
 scroll.setScrollingEnabledX(false);
```

and this css of scrollPanel
     .loginScroll {
    height: 90%;
    width: 100%;
      }

if I run application in computer is work fine but I run on on smartphone is not work
I upload two videos 
1) application run on computer 
http://s250.photobucket.com/user/gallavie/media/V_20140501_080006_zps08263060.mp4.html
2) application run on android 
http://s250.photobucket.com/user/gallavie/media/V_20140501_075801_zps121a5bc5.mp4.html

I hope this help to solve the problem

Comment: I have used it many times without problem. Try this url with your phone (http://mobilegwt.appspot.com/showcase/#ScrollWidgetPlace). Check your imports and see if you are using mgwt's scrollPanel really.

Comment: Check your LayoutPanels, post a small example if possible.

Answer (score 0):

setStyleName replaces the scrollpanel css with yours, that's one reason it does not work. Try it without it.

To apply style to the scrollpanel try this: [scrollPanel.addStyleName()](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/style.html)

Comment: but if I remove style from scollPanel I not see the scrollPanel on the android I see just the title

Comment: Try adding the ScrollPanel in a LayoutPanel which takes all the screen automatically

Comment: and how I can set style of scrollPanel?